# Вызвать функцию из цикла

Tags: python, python-3.x

помогите пожалуйста исправить скрипт

```
import datetime
import time

def nowTime():
    nowTime = datetime.datetime.now()
    return str(nowTime)

while True:
    nowTime = nowTime()  
    time.sleep(1)
    print(nowTime)
```

проблема в том, что функция nowTime() не вызывается. сообщение об ошибке такое:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "C:\VINT\OPENSERVER\OpenServer\domains\localhost\python\parse_html\2_vk_fiends\q.py",
> line 11, in <module>
>     nowTime = nowTime() TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Никогда не используй имена переменных аналогичные именам функций и проблем таких знать не будешь

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В питоне все - объект

```
nowTime = nowTime()
```

В переменную nowTime в первое прохождение цикла записывается строчка. А во второе прохождение цикла эта переменная вызывается как функция, но так как она теперь строка, а не функция, она не может быть вызвана.

Если вы помните, то doc у функций вызывается как свойство объекта:

```
>>> print len.__doc__
len(object) -> integer

Return the number of items of a sequence or mapping.
```

И точно так же можно убедиться, что переменная содержит функцию

```
def nowTime():
    nowTime = datetime.datetime.now()
    return str(nowTime)

>>> nowTime
<function nowTime at 0x02A9D470>
```